# How to create downloadable file link for the file to download in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, download, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Previously I was sending file as `Byte array` from ASP.net core 2.0 and in Angular 4 application I am calling below function to download the file

```
function (response) { // Here response is byte array
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", this.zipLocation + ".zip");
    link.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

But now I want to send the file path from the server like below

`https://websiteaddress/file/path/to/download.ext`

So in Angular 5, I can directly attach link to `href` attribute of anchor tag and will make automatic click on that. So I don't need to **Convert byte array to url**

**Here the issue is I don't know how to create that downloadable file path using ASP.net core and send it to frontend**

And also I want to know, which approach is better, whether sending `Byte array` or `Sending the direct link`? Is there any performance issue with any of the two?

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using api response as file data

add `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` in request header.

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<a (click)="downLoad()">Click To Download</a>
```

TS:

```
downLoad(){

 this.fileService.getFileFromServer(fileId.toString()).subscribe(respData => {
            this.downLoadFile(respData, this.type);
        }, error => {

        });
   }




/**
 * Method is use to download file.
 * @param data - Array Buffer data
 * @param type - type of the document.
 */
downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var pwa = window.open(url);
    if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
        console.log('Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again');
    }
}
```

file-service.ts:

```
getFileFromServer(id){
        return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers});
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I think, I am wasting SO people guys time. But my issue is with server not with Angular. At frontend I can handle, but from server using ASP.net core, how can I create downloadable file link. Once again thank you for your precious time

Comment: Yes I am getting the data from server. And there is no problem with response I am getting. But problem is with how to create downloadable file link using ASP.net core

Answer (score -1):

your question make confuse about angular frontend and backend
frontend you can use mvc

```
<a asp-controller="Controller"
   asp-action="Download" 
   asp-route-id="@Model.FileName">Download @Model.FileName</a>
```

or using angular

```
<a href="/Controller/Download?name=myFileName.ext">Download</a>
<a [href]="ControllerRoute+'/Download?name='+fileName" download>Download {{fileName}}</a>
```

Ok maybe your problem is your action (in controller) doesnt server a file
you need return a `HttpResponse` with a MediaType, this is just a example, dont forget best practices on your code

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetDownloadableFIle(string name)
{
    try
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var filePath = $"{MyRootPath}/{name}";
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath );

        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

        var mediaType = "application/octet-stream";
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new  System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString()));
    }
}
```